# "Cthulhu Fhtagn" - is there a rule how to pronounce artificially created words?

Tags: pronunciation

[image: Cthulhu]

There are many such words in a fiction literature, including *Jabberwocky*, *Cthulhu*, *Kilrathi*, and many others. Of course, the authors intended to make these words appear most uncommon to an English reader, and it must have been a **deliberate attempt to make the pronunciation unclear**.

Being an English learner, I, most likely, have read those books translated to my language, so it is very possible that my pronunciation is somewhat spoiled (even if my language uses Latin alphabet).

An obvious way is googling for each individual word to see how it is *suggested* to pronounce each one. However, this is not the case if you are involved in a spoken discussion. You simply have no possibility to search.

So, **is there any simple, mnemonic rule how to pronounce an arbitrary artificially created word?**

**Update**: I see close-votes on this question, so I have to explain myself.
Not knowing how to pronounce a word may lead you to an embarrassing situation.
Actually, a comic below illustrates very well what happens if you pronounce **R'lyeh** wrongly:

[image: R'lyeh mispronounced]
<sup>image from [here](http://playdesignplay.tumblr.com/post/35132896646/girls-laughing-ryleh)</sup>

Comment: Sure: If it doesn't look like English, guess. ... Really, same answer (*mutatis mutandis*) as I gave [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/2563/32); a rule would take all the fun out of it. :-)

Comment: By the way, as a polyglot you would probably enjoy [this](http://www.waxdog.com/jabberwocky/translate.html).

Comment: @StoneyB LOL at the Klingon translation!

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. English doesn't really even have many "rules" telling you how to pronounce *actual* words, which are *not* deliberately created in order to sound "strange". Besides, unless you're trying to talk to other people at an [H. P. Lovecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Call_of_Cthulhu) convention, what difference does it make how Lovecraft (or indeed anyone else) pronounces it?

Comment: @WendiKidd  The German is brilliant: Dann, stehend unterm Tumtum Baum, Er an-zu-denken-fing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Added rationale.

Comment: Umm... Correct me if I'm wrong, but surely the whole *point* of that "joke" is that people don't know how to pronounce that made-up word? We're not laughing *with* the girls at some poor shmuck who doesn't know what they think *they* know - we're laughing *at* them for supposing they know the right pronunciation of the word in the first place!

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're exactly right, of course, that there are no rules to pronounce fictitious words.  I wonder, though, if the fact that the answer to the question "Are there rules" is "No" makes the question Not Constructive? If others come along with this same question, and see this question along with the answer "No, there really aren't any rules for pronouncing fictitious words" ...etc, well, they got their question answered, right? Even though the answer is no. (Honestly wondering your opinion-I'm not sure how to handle such questions on ELL. Perhaps a topic for meta.)

Comment: @WendiKidd http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149429/is-theres-no-answer-an-answer

Comment: @FumbleFingers The "joke" is about derogatory meaning caused by improper pronunciation.

Comment: @WendiKidd: It's early days for the site, and it'll probably be some time before a consensus emerges as to what kind of uestions we do and don't want to cover here. That's why I think it's particularly important we should participate in early Meta discussions. There aren't really any "rules" until we decide collectively what they should be.

Comment: @bytebuster: You've lost me there. Apparently those who listen to "Dark Adventure Radio Theatre" know it's pronounced "Rill-yeah" (at least, in the context of that radio drama series). But how is pronouncing it differently "derogatory"?

Comment: It's not a mnemonic, but the sometimes the easiest thing to do is wait for the movie ;^)

Comment: I think for made-up words the only "rule" is to ask the person who made it up how it should be pronounced.

Comment: Actually, the authors of Jabberwocky and Call of Cthulhu both made attempts to show how their nonsense words are pronounced. Tolkien certainly did also.

Comment: In this case the rule is that "Chthulu fhtagn" must be preceded by "Ia! Ia!" (those are capital "I"s (eye), not lower-case "L" (ell)) screamed at the top of one's lungs, generally while running away. Away from *what* we probably don't want to discuss, but...away. Quickly. With much alacrity. And screaming. Loud screaming. Run. Fast. Scream. Loud. Ia! Ia!

Comment: @J.R. - yeah, but the movies usually get it WRONG! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.  There are no such rules.

However, there are *tendencies*.  Words tend to be pronounced like other words they look similar to.  For example, if I wrote the following words, I would expect them all to rhyme with piffle:

- Liffle
- Griffle
- Shiffle
- Miffle
- Tiffle

However, if I wrote the following words, it'd be ambiguous because there are similar-looking English words with differing pronunciations (bough, though, through, rough, you):

- Fough
- Yough
- Sough
- Mough
- Wough

The pronunciation isn't well-specified in the first set of words *or* the second, but with the first, I can tell how they're *probably* pronounced.  With the second set, I can imagine any number of pronunciations.

Your example, "Cthulhu Fhtagn", fits into a third category.  It doesn't resemble any English words!  The only reason I know how to pronounce "Cthulhu" is that I've heard it pronounced.  "Fhtagn", on the other hand, I've never heard, so I have no idea.  When you can't guess a pronunciation, you have to ask the creator of the word how they intended to pronounce it, or (if the word has become widespread) ask someone who's heard it how they pronounce it.

For another example, look at Tolkien's made-up words and names.  How would you pronounce Cirdan?  If you didn't know what Tolkien intended, there'd be a number of plausible pronunciations.

But take heart.  If you pronounce a made-up word incorrectly, you're in good company.

Comment: Tolkien, however, tells you how to pronounce the words of his languages.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the real answer: to know where the author drew his inspiration from. Tolkien was a linguist and was very precise about his languages. I seem to recall editions of the LOTR coming with pronunciation and definition guides (and if this was a real answer, I would look them up). Similarly, some authors are clearly going with a Celtic theme and for pronunciation you would want to look there. It's not clear where Lovecraft got his inspiration, though I wouldn't be surprised if someone has the precise answer to that and therefore the pronunciation key.